# An issue when getting data from an API in Flutter with Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having an issue with my app, I'm creating a flutter app to track cryptocurrency prices.
The issue is that I get the data properly from the API, then I print it into the counsel but when I try to display it inside the app, it displays null.

**Here is the code I use to get the data from the API**

```
class CurrencyData { var decodedData;
Future getCoinsData() async {

http.Response response =
    await http.get(coinUrl);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  decodedData = jsonDecode(response.body);
} else {
  print(response.statusCode);
  throw 'Problem with the request, try again later!';
}
return decodedData;
}
}
```

**Here is the code where I call the data to display it.**

```
class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {
CurrencyData currencyData = CurrencyData();
  var btcPrice;
  var btcChange24h;
void cryptoCurrencyData() async {
    var data = await currencyData.getCoinsData();
print(btcPrice = data['data'][0]['priceUsd']);
print(btcChange24h = data['data'][0]['changePercent24Hr']);
}
@override
  void initState() {
super.initState();
cryptoCurrencyData();
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
child: ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
        // the top bar
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
              constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: 175),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black26,
                    blurRadius: 20.0,
                    // has the effect of softening the shadow
                    spreadRadius:
                        5.0, // has the effect of extending the shadow
                  ),
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
                ),
              ),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Crypto Tracker',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 30.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // the body part
            CurrencyWidget(
              currencyIconUrl: 'assets/images/btc.png',
              currencyName: 'Bitcoin',
              currencyShortName: 'BTC',
              currencyPrice: btcPrice,
              currencyChange24h: btcChange24h,
            ),
```

I get the data printed into the console but I also get Null displayed in the emulator as shown in the below screenshot.

[The image where null is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VWtf.png)

[A screenshot of the data being printed in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KitTP.png)

**Any idea what the issue may be?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that getting api data is async task so it takes time, while build method build screen in that time, so it is printing null.

1) You can call **setState** at the end of function which change null to actual data when it gets from API.

```
void cryptoCurrencyData() async {
    var data = await currencyData.getCoinsData();
    btcPrice = data['data'][0]['priceUsd'];  // assign
    btcChange24h = data['data'][0]['changePercent24Hr']; // aasign
   print(btcPrice = data['data'][0]['priceUsd']);
   print(btcChange24h = data['data'][0]['changePercent24Hr']);
      setState(() {}); // added
   }
```

2) However, FutureBuilder is more better option where you can show loading indicator or something which shows data is loading and display when arrives.

Note: in this way you don't need **cryptoCurrencyData** method and also you don't need to store value in different variable.

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: currencyData.getCoinsData(),
        builder: (_, sanpshot) {
          if (!sanpshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          return CurrencyWidget(
            currencyIconUrl: 'assets/images/btc.png',
            currencyName: 'Bitcoin',
            currencyShortName: 'BTC',
            currencyPrice: data['data'][0]['priceUsd'],
            currencyChange24h: data['data'][0]['changePercent24Hr'],
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: Thank You so much, the setState option worked fine, I will move on with it because I'm still beginner and not familiar with the FutureBuilder. But, I will study it today. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to hear that it work for you. You you found my answer useful then accept it, so othe community members can also get benefit.